# Can't set selected options in Slack dialog select element

Tags: slack-api

I am working with dialogs in Slack and select lists. I am trying to set the `selected_options` default value but I am still getting the placeholder.

```
{
    "label": "Are these notes private?",
    "type": "select",
    "name": "private_notes",
    "optional": "true",
    "hint": "Public notes are automatically published to #heartbeat",
    "options": [{'label': 'yes', 'value': 'yes'}, {'label': 'no', 'value': 'no'}],
    'selected_options': [{'label': 'no', 'value': 'no'}],
}
```

result:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

The `selected_options` property only works for **dynamic** select menus, not for **static** ones. And btw. there no point in setting multiple defaults for a select menu. It can only have one default.

To set a default value for a static select menu use the property `value`.

Example for setting `yes` as default:

```
{
    "label": "Are these notes private?",
    "type": "select",
    "value": "yes",
    "name": "private_notes",
    "optional": "true",
    "hint": "Public notes are automatically published to #heartbeat",
    "options": [{'label': 'yes', 'value': 'yes'}, {'label': 'no', 'value': 'no'}]
}
```

Also see [here](https://api.slack.com/dialogs#select_elements) for reference in the official documentation.